# Testing Contract Runs Out of Gas Truffle

Tags: contract-development, truffle

Trying to figure out why I get an out of gas error in my truffle tests when I have the following function:

```
function updateField(address someAddress, uint256 someId, bool someBool) public {
  SomeStruct storage item = myMap[someAddress];
  require(msg.sender == someAddress || msg.sender == owner);
  require(item.owner != address(0));
  item.mapInItem[someId].someVal = someBool; // when I comment out this line the error goes away
}
```

The thing is when I comment out the last line the error goes away! Anyone know why this might be happning and how to fix it.

Comment: Maybe you didn't provide enough gas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add the following to my truffle.js configuration:

`solc: { optimizer: { enabled: true, runs: 200 } },`

The optimizer is disabled by default now.